# Why the 'RUST_LOG' environment variable is not working?

Tags: powershell, environment-variables

I was working with `log` and `env_logger` crate and its documentation says that we can set the `RUST_LOG` environment variable to different levels to filter out logs of lower-level, `RUST_LOG=debug` will filter out all logs of `trace` level.
I tried running this command `RUST_LOG=debug cargo run` and i get this following error

```
RUST_LOG=debug : The term 'RUST_LOG=debug' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was 
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

how do i solve this?

Comment: Judging from the error message, you are using powershell.
The syntax you used above in specific to unix shells, and therefore doesn't work.
Try using `$env:RUST_LOG = 'debug'` followed by `cargo run` instead

Comment: i tried doing that ```$env:RUST_LOG = trace``` and i get the following error```trace : The term 'trace' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that 
the path is correct and try again.```

Comment: You should use a string: `$env:RUST_LOG="debug"; cargo run`.